# Tensorflow: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python' has no attribute 'control_flow_ops'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using keras ver `1.0.8` and tensorflow ver `0.12.0`.
I ran  `python image_zooms_training.py -n 0`
 then it throws

> `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python' has no attribute 'control_flow_ops'

please tell me how to solve . thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Following import works. You need to update that line

```
from tensorflow.python.ops import control_flow_ops
```

Comment: thank you for answer. i wrote it but it did'nt work. Moreover ,

Comment: Exception ignored in: <bound method BaseSession.__del__ of <tensorflow.python.client.session.Session object at 0x7fe506bf7a58>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/satan/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 581, in __del__
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'TF_DeleteStatus'

Comment: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'TF_DeleteStatus'  this error is solved

Comment: the error concerned in this question is resolved. you have other errors not related to this question or answer

Answer (score 0):

Official TensorFlow Support discourages use of tf.python.* as it is private and intended for development purposes only. While it may work in some cases, it will "break unannounced" in many others.

Instead, try importing tensorflow with the .python portion removed, e.g.:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
```